# How does SAP ABAP system find out and suggest foreign key automatically for a table?

Tags: abap

I have 2 tables: ZDEPARTMENT and it's text table ZDEPARTMENTT

For table ZDEPARTMENTT.DEPARTMENT the domain is ZDEPARTMENT
and the domain ZDEPARTMENT does not have a associated value table.

Yet, the SAP system makes the correct suggestion for foreign key for ZDEPARTMENTT.DEPARTMENT as ZDEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENT

How is SAP able to make the correct suggestion even if the domain of the foreign key field does not have any value in VALUE TABLE field?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: The text table has the same key + the language column and is therefore recognized as a text table fo zdepartment

Comment: I could not reproduce the situation or I don't understand correctly. The checktable field is automatically filled when the screen starts? Of course, after directly entering the check table SAP loads and compares the key fields then make a proposal. Did you write everything in your post that could be related? `INT_DD_FORKEY_EDIT` shows the foreign key screen and fills the values, you should debug it for finding the answer you need.